# Find out what your supervisor can do

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

Is the following sentence grammatical and idiomatic? The context is to ask the call center staff, who told me that his supervisor will help to look into a matter, and he is not sure about the right of his supervisor in this matter.

> Can you help me to find out what your supervisor can do for this
>   matter?

Comment: It's not clear what your difficulty is with this phrase.  It seems you are just asking us to check the sentence for correctness.

Answer (score 1):

The supervisor would do something **regarding** this matter or **about** this matter, not **for** this matter.

Otherwise, it's OK, although perhaps a little long.  I think a native would more likely shorten it to "Can you help me find out..." or even just "Can you find out..."

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> What can your supervisor do [about this matter]?